# C++ accessing struct variable causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sockets, struct, memcpy

I have this part of code:

```
int connectingSocket,port;
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
struct hostent *server;
server = gethostbyname("localhost");
if(server = NULL)
    dataFile << "Error finding a host!" << std::endl;
port = 7017;
connectingSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(connectingSocket < 0)
    dataFile << "Error opening a socket" << std::endl;
memset(&server_address,0,sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
memcpy(&(server_address.sin_addr.s_addr), server->h_addr_list,server->h_length);
```

I am sure that the last line throws Segmentation fault(Core dumped) error,but I am not sure what the problem is.I tried printing out sizes of the variables.

```
std::cout << sizeof(server_address.sin_addr.s_addr) << " - " << sizeof(server->h_addr_list) << std::endl;
```

This line prints "4 - 8",shouldn't the results be the same if I want to copy?

Also:

```
std::cout << server->h_length << std::endl;
```

This line alone causes Segmentation fault.So I believe accessing this variable causes the problem.I need your help to fix it!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if(server = NULL)` it's not comparison to null.
you should use == instead. it might be the reason of your problem : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect `if` statememt:

`if(server = NULL)`

should be:

`if(server == NULL)`

You set `server` to NULL, and then attempt to dereference a NULL pointer.

However, even if `server` was NULL, your code goes on and dereferences `server` anyway.  You should be bypassing the code that uses `server` in that case.

Comment: Silly,that I wasted 2 hours and still didn't notice ^_^

Comment: It didn't bypass the code because when I set server to NULL,the server->h_length isn't what it is supposed to be is it?

Comment: If `server` is NULL, then `server->` is wrong, since you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.  But the issue is that even if you wrote the code correctly, and `server` came back as NULL, what did your code do?  The only thing it did was print a message, and then what?  It used `server` anyway, as if there wasn't an error.

Comment: Oh,I thought you were talking about the line of the code.Yeah,I know that it only prints out an error and doesn't exit the program.Anyways,why if returns false when it is assingment operation inside?